# Spring - QueryDSL - SQL Server 2008 offset/limit issue

Tags: spring, limit, offset, querydsl

T am new to QueryDSL. I am using QueryDSL with Spring and SQL Server 2008.
Trying to execute a stored procedure and paginate it using QueryDSL offset and limit.

First, below is how I handle : SELECT * FROM storedProcedureName() 
I am not sure it is the correct way to achieve that since I did not find any example but it seems to work.

```
    SQLTemplates dialect = new SQLServer2005Templates();
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = new SQLQuery( dialect );
    StringExpression sp = StringTemplate.create( "storedProcedureName()" );
    StringExpression a = StringTemplate.create( "*" );
    sqlQuery.from( sp );

    ArrayList<Sd> _Mapping = (ArrayList<Sd>) queryDslJdbcTemplate.query(
            sqlQuery,
            new SdRowMapper(), a );
```

To handle pagination, I just add the offset and limit methods : sqlQuery.from( sp ).offset(5).limit(10) . 
 But I am getting "The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause" error.

select * from ( select row_number() over () as rn
from storedProcedureName()) a where rn > ? and rn <= ? order by rn.

So I am sure I am not doing it the right way. Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, It is not a stored procedure but a table valuated function. 
So I made something proper using that link : https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/35 <br/>

    RelationalFunctionCall<String> functionCall = RelationalFunctionCall.create(String.class, "functionName");

But I still have the same issue with the paging methods.. (I think it is because the order clause is empty :<br/> `[ select row_number() over ( ..ID here.. ) ]` .<br/> And I am guessing that is empty because when QueryDSL generates the query, it is looking for a kind of ID, not found since it is not defined..

Comment: So If I am right, I should find a way to define manually the column to set it in the Order by clause..

Regarding the query projection, even if the use of <br/> `StringExpression a = StringTemplate.create( "*" );` <br/>seems to work, I don't think it is a good idea but I defined it like that because I did not find a way to use the returnedTable.all() ..    

And with Spring and the QueryDslJdbcTemplate, the list(projection... ) method raises a null exception from AbstractSQLQuery.. Maybe because I did not set any Connection arg in the SQLQuery constructor. 

I know it is a lot of guessing..

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide orderBy info for the query to work.